# Redirect 301 query string htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to redirect query string link to another link in my .htaccess file I've been following some guides and I figured out how to do that so at the moment the redirect is done but it doesn't really work like I would like.

This is the first link:
http://www.mydomain.it/index.php?page=lkr_pg_chisiamo

That should be redirected to this one: 
https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/

This is what I've done in my htaccess in wordpress:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=lkr_pg_chisiamo$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/ [R=301,L]
```

Now the redirect works but my final URL is: 
https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/?page=lkr_pg_chisiamo

What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the redirect works but my final URL is:
>   https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/?page=lkr_pg_chisiamo

You need to discard the query string. Two solutions:

### Solution 1 (using `?` to reset new query string)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/? [R=301,L]
```

### Solution 2 (using [QSD](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```